# extract data from json using python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract certain information from the json data using python. The data is something like this:

```
{
  
  "properties": {
    "detectedName": "servername1",
    
    
    "cpuCores": 60,
       },
  
      
    ]
    
  }
}
```

I need to be able to retrieve all of this data in csv. But for started, I would need "detectedName" and "cpuCores".

I tried this:

```
data['detectedName']['cpuCores'])
```

I get 'detectedName' not found error.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `detectedName`: `name = data['properties']['detectedName']`

To get `cpuCores`: `cores = data['properties']['cpuCores']`

These have to be on different lines, and are also both under the `properties` key.

Comment: this is good but if I have thousands of data files, I need to be able to read each data file and extract 'detectedName' and 'cpuCores' from them. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you need to write like this: data['properties']['detectedName']
or data['properties']['cpuCores']